# CSS-only dropdown mega menu with hover delay

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS only dropdown mega menu. Now I need to add delay on hover, but only when not already hovering a tab. The goal is to remove the delay before showing subsequent sheets - without using JavaScript. It may or or may not be possible. I have tried using sibling selector to set zero transition delay on the neighbour of the hovered element - this  naturally doesn't work because the transition delay rule applies to the 'to' hover state, not the 'from' state.

```css
body * {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #0001;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0s;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

ul li:hover button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

ul li:hover div {
  visibility: visible;
}

ul li:not(:hover) div {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>Link</button>
    <div>Sheet</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Link</button>
    <div>Sheet</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href='#'>Background link</a>
```

Comment: Can't to this without JS, your problem with css is when you are trying to go left. Either way, my two cents is that click is better for a menu then hover.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want. adding transition delay on the hover state not the actual element css

`ul li:hover div{visibility: visible;transition-delay: 1000ms;}`

```css
body * {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #0001;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul li div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: visibility 0s;
  
}

ul li:hover button {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

ul li:hover div {
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 1000ms;
}

ul li:not(:hover) div {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>Link</button>
    <div>Sheet</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button>Link</button>
    <div>Sheet</div>
  </li>
</ul>
<a href='#'>Background link</a>
```

Comment: No this still has a delay when moving between menu items

Comment: so you dont want delay when switching between menu's?